# Who installed SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, installation

Is there any way to find out who installed  SQL server on a Windows 2003 server?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the correct auditing is turned on, and the security event log hasn't rolled over it'll be in there.  Failing that it may not be.

You could look at NTFS file permissions and ownership, and what accounts have sysadmin rights and possibly figure it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it gave us insight on who is playing with our SQL servers.